# How to add action buttons to subsections of long lists

Tags: lists, scrolling, actions

When having a potentially long list with different subsections (in this case - Augmented and Unaugmented Targets) how can you add action items to the subsections (like the export button) - which are also visible while scrolling the list (so you can also quickly export when you are at the bottom of the list of a sublist?

[image: Sidebar List with Subsections]

Or to make it more clear:

- How can the export button be easily accessible at all times?
- How can the different subsection headers (Augmented Targets, Unaugmented
  Targets) easily accessible at all times?

The problem with the current solution is that the subsection headers must be sticky - but if the "Augmented Targets" header is sticky - how can I then easily navigate to the "Unaugmented Targets"?

Comment: Your question is very confusing and the illustration is not helping much. Is this some sort of side bar i'm seeing? Could you improve your illustration a bit to show some "movement"?

Comment: Why don't use tabs? IMO is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs will definitely be a better option in this case. But remember if you wish to include more subsections later on, tabs may not work out. Tabs will work best for a max of 3 subsections (4 if you can squeeze it in). Also, since export seems to be the only action you can take on the screen, consider a Material Design inspired FAB(Floating Action Button). It can always float on top of the content. It will also allow it to remain separated from the sorting options.

[image: Suggested design]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Tabs]

As mentioned by @Guz, I'd go with Tabs as well.
You can easily switch between different lists and have an "actions" row right after the tabs. It's also clear that the actions are related to the list selected.

And of course, you can keep the header, tabs row and actions row all 'sticky'. If the list is really long, and the name of the Project is not really relevant to understand the list, I would make only the tabs and actions 'sticky'.